# Как вывести все полученные GET запросы?

Tags: php

У меня есть страница з GET запросами http://example.com/index.php?1=1&2=2&3=3&4=4.
Как передать все GET запросы дальше в iframe чтобы получилось вот так?

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/block.php?1=1&2=2&3=3&4=4"></iframe>
```

Запросы не всегда с одинаковыми параметрами. По этому не получится через

```
<?php echo $_GET['1'] . $_GET['2'] . $_GET['3'] . $_GET['4'] ; ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php - parse_url и отдавайте query дальше

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Все получилось.

Comment: `<?= http_build_query($_GET) ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/block.php?<?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY); ?>"></iframe>
```